# Publish my App without going through the App store?

Tags: iphone, ios, deployment, publish

I have an App just for our clients, this app is based on a web system. Clients have their private authorization to login the App.
The quantity of clients is depend on the sales of the web system.

I'm not sure this private app can passed by app review, and how can I deploy this app to our client's iphone.
Sorry for my poor English, I do need help for this question, the date of selling the product is getting closer and closer. HELP PLEASE!!

Comment: What platform is this app for? The answer will vary greatly depending on whether you are looking at a Mac App, iOS, Android, Ovi (Nokia) etc. [Edit: you said iPhone in question]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [Distributing Enterprise Apps for iOS 4 Devices](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/FA_Wireless_Enterprise_App_Distribution/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: Thanks for answering, I will ask for my boss to apply for a Enterprise ID

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry, but without jailbreaking (For a definition, see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS_jailbreaking) wikipedia article) the recipient iPhone, you cannot get an unapproved app onto an iPhone.

Since the app is still in development, you can easily test the app on a iPhone using the iOS Development tools, however this is only a limited method of distribution: it would likely be unsuitable for general resale of an app to the public.

Finally, if an App cannot get through Apple's guidelines and approval process, they probably don't want it on their iPhones. This could be because it is illegal, has damaging content or their just being a bit monopolising.